# Controlar el tamaño en el que se muestra un formulario

Tags: html, css

Buenas, estoy creando una pagina la cual tiene la opcion para imprimir un formulario como si fuera word, este formulario es hecho con Boostrap y un poco de css, incluye texto, imagenes, etc. Es algo asi como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar solo queda un pequeño espacio en blanco en la parte de abajo, el problema aqui es cuando se hace lo mismo pero en un monitor con una resolucion mayor o menor a la mia ya que en una menor este formulario se divide en 2 paginas o hasta 3 y en una mayor el espacio blanco se hace enorme.

Mi pregunta es si existe una manera de controlar que se muestra tal y como se ve en la imagen sin importar la resolucion de donde se este proyectando.

Una disculpa si siente que esto es un post off-topic pero en verdad necesito aclarar esta duda y preferentemente solucionar este problema, gracias.

Este formulario lo dibujo dinamicamente en este div:

```
<div id="muestra1">
</div>
```

Lo que e intentado hasta ahora es tratar de controlar la vista de impresion con esto:

```
.pagebreak { page-break-before: always; }
        p {
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 1;
        }

        @page {
            size: A4 landscape;
            margin-left: 18mm;
            margin-top: 0.2mm;
        }

        .marco {
            word-break: break-all;
        }
```

Espero que se vea tal y como en la imagen en 1 sola hoja, al mostrarlo en una resolucion menor se muestra lo mismo pero se divide en 2 o mas hojas, y en una resolucion mayor el espacio en blanco se hace mas grande.

**Editado:**

En esta imagen se muestra un ejemplo de mi problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero saber es si es posible mostrar el contenido siempre en una solo hoja.

**Editado #2**

Codigo HTML completo:

[Ejemplo HTML](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRPaoq)

Comment: La pregunta no es off-topic, pero le falta información clave para poder ayudarte: ¿A qué espacio en blanco te refieres?¿Podrías incluir imágenes de cómo se ve en las otras pantallas y cómo querrías que se viese?¿Podrías incluir algo de código (no importa que sea falso) con HTML y CSS con el que se pueda ver el problema (lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))?

Comment: Listo, solo me falto agregar imagenes pero no tengo acceso a los otros equipos de computo.

Comment: Agregue una imagen en donde se puede apreciar el problema.

Comment: Tendriamos que ver gran parte de tu código para poder entender más tu problema. Pienso que tiene que ver con las resoluciones de pantalla que maneja bootstrap.

Comment: Agregue un link donde pueden ver un ejemplo de todo el codigo HTML que dibujo y a su vez pueden ver el cambio con sus respectivas resoluciones de pantalla.

Comment: Puedes intentar con la función de bootstrap printArea() del siguiente [enlace](http://librosweb.es/foro/pregunta/398/como-agregar-la-funcion-imprimir-en-bootstrap/)

Comment: @Irwing Aproveche el ejemplo para mostrarte mi problema, si le das a imprimir veras que en la pagina 2 se escriben 2 lineas, ese es mi mismo problema quiero que todo se escriba en una sola pagina, te dejo el ejemplo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXBwdp

Comment: @FranciscoFernandez, entiendo pero a mí me aparece bien la página. Creo que eso que quieres hacer ya es cosa de la propia configuración del navegador del lado del cliente.

Comment: A mi tambien me aparece bien en las resoluciones de 1600x900 y 1366 x 768 pero e probado otras y no funcionaba bien y supuse eso de que no habia forma de controlarlo asi que lo que hice fue hacer el template como un tipo de word donde se cambie el tama;o de la fuente y se arrastren las imagenes.

Comment: Si al imprimir tienes demasiadas cosas y cupa demasiado, has considerado crear una versión imprimible con menos cosas para que ocupe menos ? Seguro que hay cosas que no necesitas que aparezcan en una versión imprimible

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo no entendí del todo tu problema, pero si quieres controlar la resolución de tu pantalla y que se adapte en función al monitos podrías agregar un estilo a tu vista de tal modo que se adapte al tamaño:
Ejemplo:

```
.contenedor {
    min-width: 700px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;

}
```

Comment: Enseguida lo pruebo... se que no se entiende muy bien la pregunta pero te comento, por ejemplo en mi monitor se muestra del 1 al 10 (un numero por renglon) al momento de probarlo en una resolucion menor se muestra del 1 al 6 y de ahi se crea la pagina dos (esta muestra del 7 al 10) y en una resolucion mayor se muestra del 1 al 10 pero deja como 1/4 de pagina en blanco.

Answer (score 0):

Es bastante complicado lo que buscas, te puedo dar dos opciones que he usado anteriormente:

Si tienes control sobre el server te recomiendo crear un html o algun template como handlebars y de ahi convertirlo a pdf, para node podrias usar https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ que es una libreria para convertir html a pdf, ya de ahi creas el servicio y el cliente en cualquier dispositivo tendra la misma impresion.

Si no tienes control sobre el server podrias probar con el media print del navegador, asi aplicas estilos solo en el medio de impresion, algo asi:

```
<style media="print">
 #sidebar {
    display:none;
 }
```

Espero haberte dado alguna idea de como solucionar tu problema, por mi me iria con el pdf, ahorra varios dolores de cabeza.

Answer (score 0):

Desde css puedes controlar lo que imprimes, su formato y su presentacion, esto pasa por crear una nueva css para media print.

Tienes que tener en cuenta que a la hora de imprimir es como si mostraras el contenido en otra pantalla y el tamaño de esta será el de el papel predefinido en la impresora.
No puedes meter mas contenido que el que cabe en la pagina y si sobrepasa el final te genera una página nueva.

Por lo general el formato de tu pantalla será un DIN A4, pero podría ser cualquier tamaño soportado por la impresora